# Play button centred with different image/video sizes

Tags: css, video

How can I keep the play button centred even if the the image/video size changed?

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    width:500px; //changed
    height:300px;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nGKcn/) is my example...

Attention: my images/videos haven't no specific size, so they can change according to their own size... This is just an example!

Comment: Do you want your image to determine the width and/or height of the `.image` container, or do you want the image to fit into `.image` when `.image` has specified dimensions?  This problem can be solved several ways.  Can you tell us a more?

Comment: I want the image to fit into `.image`! However the dimensions are not specified in css code, like it happens in my example. The image is presented according to their own size, so they can have any size...

Comment: You are relatively new to SO and I see that you have asked a few questions and gotten good answers.  Accept some answers that you say are good and up vote others that have helped you.  Reputation points are the only payment we get for helping each other.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set up three examples to show how you could solve this problem.

Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/mxSkQ/

The HTML is essentially yours:

```
<div class ="image ex1">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150" alt="video">
        <span class="play">
            <span></span>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I am using a demo image with configurable dimensions, 200x150 for example, easily changed for testing.

**Example 1 - Image Size Determines Size of the Parent Container**

```
.ex1.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.image a {
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative;
}

/* Gets rid of the extra white space that follows an inline element*/
.image img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

If you want the `.image` div to shrink to fit the image, use `inline-block` to display.
The `margin-left` is optional, will depend on the rest of the layout.

**Important:** To center the play button motif, simply set the `a` tag to display as `inline-block` and your arrow-motif-span will position itself nicely.

Because `img` is an inline element, browsers insert a small space after it that can show up if you have borders or backgrounds.  Use `vertical-align: bottom` to clean that up.

**Example 2 - Parent Container Has A Specified Width**

You can specify a width for the `.image` parent container and then use `text-align` to position the image element.

```
.ex2.image {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Example 3 - Parent Container Has Full Width and Specified Height**

In this example, I let the parent container fill up the width of the window and set the 
height to 200px.  To get vertical centering, I set `margin-top` to a hard-coded value that will depend on the height of the image.  If you let the image take on a fixed height, this example is useful.

```
.ex3.image {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}

.ex3.image a {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation Marc! I'm trying to implement it on my real case, but with no sucess, because the play button stays fixed to a position. Can you have a look at it please?
Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/dzfsX/2/

Comment: I would be happy to help you. Your modifications merit another question.  Please open another question and post the link to your new question.  The layout is different and needs some adjustments.  First, accept this answer since and up vote if you have not done so. I will then look for your new question and answer it.  Thank you.

Comment: Where is the link to the new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795057/css-play-button-image-centred-and-on-top-of-video-div-according-to-different-vi Thank you

Comment: I got your link.  Please up vote and accept the answer to this question and then I will look at your second question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; // top and left equal to half of the size * (-1)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nGKcn/13/

Try playing with the image size/different images.

Answer (score 0):

Give the image CSS of:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

This is just a general way you put stuff in the middle.

Unless I'm missing something maybe?

Comment: That doesn't work! If you try to change the picture size, the play button remains in the same position, and it doesn't "move" according to the picture size...